# Neo4j 2.0.3, Cypher: UNWIND

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to `unwind` a collection into individual rows with neo4j-2.0.3 version?

(I don't want to go by getting all the subsets of path and then choosing the last node in each subset-path to get different rows, since this will take more time.)

P.S.: `UNWIND` is only supported with neo4j-2.1.

Please help out.

Answer (score 1):

`unwind` has been backported to Neo4j 2.0.4, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.4/query-unwind.html.

So do upgrade to 2.0.4.